# Diferencia entre $value==null y null==$value

Tags: php, optimización

Cuál es la diferencia de poner el **null** delante o detras de la variable que estamos comparando, o sea, cuál es la diferencia entre:
`if ($value==null){...}` y `if (null==$value){...}`
He escuchado que la segunda opción es más eficiente desde el punto de vista del compilador, a decir verdad, no sé cuál es la diferencia.

Comment: php es un lenguaje interpretado no compilado. Con lo cual habria que leer el manual del interprete en particular que estas usando, y ver si hace alguna optimizacion en los if dependiendo de como lo escribas.

Comment: en realidad es ambos, el parser lo compila a un bytecode que luego es interpretado

Comment: en todos los manuales de programacion que he visto primero va la variable de asignacion y luego el valor a asignar, se mantienen tambien en los if digamos que es una convencion usarlo de esa manera ya que prestaria a  confusion, si la idea es que el codigo sea menos legible hacer eso es una gran opcion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cuál es la diferencia de poner el null delante o detras de la variable que estamos comparando?**

No hay diferencia salvo una convención de sintaxis.
Esto vale tanto para el que escribe el código para evitar errores de tipeo, como para el Parser (al menos en PHP) que tokeniza el código fuente para armar el syntax tree que luego se compila a bytecode que luego mediante interprete pasa a opcode (assembler de la plataforma)

Una constante como el número 42 o null es un token que tiene una regla (en el parser) por la cual no puede estar seguido de un token de asignación ( un = ) pero sí por un token de comparación ( un == )

**Por qué se usa o recomienda?**

explico con el número 42 para que sea mas claro el efecto de esta práctica. en sus casas pueden usar `null`

en PHP (y otros lenguajes) generalmente se usa para evitar errores de asignación.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$value = 40;

if ($value=42) :
  echo "$value es 42".PHP_EOL;
else :
 echo "$value NO es 42".PHP_EOL;
endif;
```

Resultado:

```
$ ./yodacondition.php
42 es 42
```

Es un ejemplo simple y podemos inferir el valor de `$value` antes del `if` es `40` asi que el error de tipeo (poner `=` en vez de `==`) es evidente.

Pero no sería tan evidente este error si $value viene de otro lado.

En cambio usando **Yoda Conditions** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$value = 40;

if (42=$value) :
  echo "$value es 42".PHP_EOL;
else :
 echo "$value NO es 42".PHP_EOL;
endif;
```

Resultado:

```
$ ./yodacondition2.php
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '='
```

Esto es debido a que 42 es una constante y no se le puede asignar un valor.

Lo de que optimiza el compilador me parece que es un mito urbano, pues los lenguajes compilados por lo general tienen optimizadores que arman tablas de comparación y salto condicional internamente para este tipo de if then else.

Edit 2: en el primer ejemplo `$value=42` no sólo asigna el valor `42` a `$value` sino que devuelve `true` satisfaciendo la condición del `if`

Comment: ¿y esto qué tiene que ver con la pregunta?

Comment: reemplaza 42 por null y tal vez le encuentres sentido

Comment: pero php no es compilado, es interpretado. por lo cual si el interprete ve null adelante, podes asegurar que no haga algun tipo de cosa para evitar hacer la comparacion?

Comment: claro segundo ejemplo, tira error

Comment: Pero la pregunta era acerca de comparar valores mediante `if`, no para saber si la asignación de valores funciona o no. O sea, comparar dos valores mediante `==`, no saber si la asignación `=` funciona o no... Oo

Comment: a ver si puedo explicarlo mejor edito la intro

Comment: Muy bien, así sí tiene sentido poner la constante delante.

Answer (score 4):

Dada la cantidad de respuestas (tres) que considero no responden a la pregunta, hice una pequeña prueba, para ver si alguno de los dos es más "rápido" o "eficiente":

> Consiste en ejecutar 1 millón de veces `if(null == $var){//}` y `if($var == null){//}`
>
> La columna con nombre 'null' es la de `if(null == $var){//}`, y la columna con nombre 'var' es la de `if($var == null){//}`

```
Iteraciones: 1000000  (20 ejecuciones)
 #  | null     | rel %   |  var      | rel %  
----+----------+---------+-----------+--------
  1 |  0.21405 |  97.2 % |   0.22014 |  102.8%
  2 |  0.21474 | 104.2 % |   0.20613 |   96.0%
  3 |  0.22034 | 103.9 % |   0.21200 |   96.2%
  4 |  0.21678 |  96.4 % |   0.22485 |  103.7%
  5 |  0.28206 | 138.0 % |   0.20432 |   72.4%
  6 |  0.37546 |  91.6 % |   0.41001 |  109.2%
  7 |  0.39286 |  98.8 % |   0.39760 |  101.2%
  8 |  0.38703 |  97.7 % |   0.39617 |  102.4%
  9 |  0.38722 |  96.7 % |   0.40030 |  103.4%
 10 |  0.33443 |  82.9 % |   0.40357 |  120.7%
 11 |  0.20490 |  87.2 % |   0.23485 |  114.6%
 12 |  0.19351 | 100.7 % |   0.19219 |   99.3%
 13 |  0.19576 |  97.3 % |   0.20112 |  102.7%
 14 |  0.19199 |  88.9 % |   0.21584 |  112.4%
 15 |  0.20707 | 100.5 % |   0.20597 |   99.5%
 16 |  0.20554 | 104.3 % |   0.19706 |   95.9%
 17 |  0.19500 |  95.1 % |   0.20504 |  105.1%
 18 |  0.19618 | 101.5 % |   0.19333 |   98.5%
 19 |  0.19848 | 102.1 % |   0.19432 |   97.9%
 20 |  0.21158 | 101.8 % |   0.20785 |   98.2%
```

En mi opinión, no hay practicamente ninguna diferencia en términos de 'velocidad' (teniendo en cuenta que hay un millón de iteraciones).

Por si acaso, la prueba se realizó con php 7.1.7

Comment: pero en terminos de legibilidad si! no es comun ver asignar un valor a null, imagina este caso ademas de que en el archivo donde esta no identen, podemos decir en cuanto a buenas practicas que se recomienda

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, sin embargo mi respuesta solo intenta responder (valga la redundancia) específicamente a la pregunta: ¿Cuál es más eficiente?

Comment: por eso deje el comentario en esta respuesta, muestra cual es optimo, solo que falto decir cual recomiendas, y como buen programador que eres se que estas de acuerdo conmigo

Answer (score 1):

Esto lo leí varias veces, no es un tema de eficiencia, es una práctica que se puede aplicar para evitar cometer el siguiente tipo de error al hacer comparaciones:

```
if(variable == 5) //bien escrito

if(5 == $variable) //bien escrito

if(variable = 5) //No es lo que queríamos pero esta bien escrito y variable ahora vale 5, 

if(5 = $variable) // Tira Error
```

Por lo tanto escribiéndolo "al revés" hacemos que tire error y no que siga funcionando y encima cambiando el valor de mi variable si nos "olvidamos" el "==".

Comment: pero OP pregunta por eficiencia.. en que ayuda esta respuesta? salvo que pareceria una "buena practica"

Comment: tambien es una buena practica en PHP, de hecho está en el coding standard de symphony (un popular framework) http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html#structure

Comment: ¿en dónde lo leíste?

Comment: En stackoverflow en ingles, lo he buscado alguna vez discutiendo sobre el tema.

Comment: Gracias @LeonardoCabré, muy buena tu respuesta, así sí tiene sentido poner el valor delante.